# Create role for the first user in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I need to create "admin" role for the first user in the database. This is my code:

```
public static void SetAdminForTheFirstUser()
        {
            using(var _db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                string roleName = "Admin";
                var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                if(!roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
                {
                    var newRoleresult = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole()
                    {
                        Name = roleName,
                    });
                    var userRole = new IdentityUserRole
                    {
                        UserId = _db.Profiles.FirstOrDefault().Id.ToString(),
                        RoleId = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Id,                    
                    };
                }            
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Is any better way to check role and create it for the first user if role doesn't exist?

Comment: Is this being done as part of a Code First migration, or is this called elsewhere?  Some additional context would help.

Comment: this is a part of Code First migration. Just template part of MVC 5 project. And then migration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this stuff in your configuration (Seed method).

```
protected override void Seed(Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    ParameterSeeder.Seed(context);
    RoleSeeder.Seed(context);
    UserSeeder.SeedAdmin(context);
    CategorySeeder.SeedMain(context);
    CategorySeeder.SeedChild(context);
    ProductUnitSeeder.Seed(context);
    ProductSeeder.Seed(context);
    ...
}
```

Inside the concerning seeders you can specify your parts:

```
internal static class RoleSeeder
{
    internal static void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var idManager = new IdentityManager();

        // Create roles
        var roleAdmin = new AllesVersRole {Description = "Administrator", Name = "Admin"};
        var roleClient = new AllesVersRole {Description = "Clienten", Name = "Client"};

        // Seed
        AddRole(idManager, roleAdmin);
        AddRole(idManager, roleClient);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private static void AddRole(IdentityManager idManager, AllesVersRole role)
    {
        if (!idManager.RoleExists(role.Name))
            idManager.CreateRole(role.Name, role.Description);
    }
}
```

I can only advice this way, as it is simple and easy to adjust